# Getting column name from column count

Tags: sql-server

I have a count that goes from 4 to 31. This count is of the columns in a table. I want to know the column name with respect to the count. My column count will be changing as i have applied a loop.
For Example : My column are F3,F4,.....F31.
My count starts from 4, at this time my column is F3. How can i get the name of the column name. Next time when count becomes 4 the pointer will move ahead to column F4. At this moment i want the column name as F4. How can I achieve this.? Following is a code that counts no of columns for me.

```
declare @col_Count int
set @col_Count = (select count(*) NoOfColumns from SYSCOLUMNS
WHERE id= (Select id from SYSOBJECTS where name = 'TEMP_STOCK_uPDATE'))
select syscolumns from dbo.TEMP_STOCK_uPDATE
```

Comment: Trying to work with columns by their ordinal "position" is usually fraught with danger. Columns should only (ideally) be referenced by name. Perhaps if you told us what problem you're trying to solve (rather than this apparent piece of a solution), we could present some better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the colorder field of syscolumns. See example below:

```
declare @colindex int
declare @colcount int
declare @tableid int
declare @colname varchar(100)

set @tableid = ( select id from sysobjects where name='name-of-table' )
set @colcount = ( select COUNT(*) from syscolumns where id = @tableid )

set @colindex = 1
while @colindex <= @colcount 
begin
  set @colname = ( select name from syscolumns where id = @tableid and colorder = @colindex )
  print @colname
  set @colindex = @colindex + 1
end
```

Comment: In SQL Server, it's often easier to work with the metadata functions than the system views.  So you could use OBJECT_ID('name-of-table') instead of the first query, and COL_NAME(@tableid, @colindex) instead of the query inside the loop.